# Unable to get the input from a textfield in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get the input from a text-field in react but it just doesn't work and I have no clue why. I have looked at a lot of different solutions but none of them seem to work.

I even tried to follow this https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html but I'm not understanding this correctly?

```
class Activity extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.newActivity = React.createRef();
}

callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/activities", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            newName: this.newActivity.current,
            oldName: this.state.activity
        }),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        });
}



state = {
    activity: this.props.data.name
}
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid justify="center" container spacing={(2, 10)} aligncontent="center">
                <Grid item xs={8} >
                    <Paper>
                        {/*Trying to get the input here so that I can put it into my POST request*/}
                        <TextField inputRef={el => this.newActivity = el} type="activity" id="standard-basic" label="Standard" defaultValue={this.state.activity} />
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button onClick={this.callAPI} variant="contained" startIcon={<UpdateIcon />} style={buttonStyle} >Uppdatera</Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button variant="contained" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} style={buttonStyle} >Ta Bort</Button>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'newActivity' of undefined

Comment: That is because of the way `callAPI()` is called, you can fix that by defining `callAPI` as `callAPI = () => {..}` or use `onClick={() => this.callAPI()}`.

Comment: You need to assign the ref like this: `inputRef={this.newActivity} `

Comment: Just to keep in mind for the future improvements; your code is smells;

Comment: @Jackson I changed it to inputRef={this.newActivity} and now I get the error "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'
    |     property '__reactInternalInstance$bxqzh2pnvoh' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle" when I click the button, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You must initiate state values inside the constructor.

Also change this line  as `inputRef={this.newActivity}` instead of `inputRef={(el)=>this.newActivity =el}`. Because you already create ref using createRef no need to create again.

```
class Activity extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activity: this.props.data.name
    }
    this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this);
    this.newActivity = React.createRef();
}

callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/activities", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            newName: this.newActivity.current,
            oldName: this.state.activity
        }),
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Grid justify="center" container spacing={(2, 10)} aligncontent="center">
                <Grid item xs={8} >
                    <Paper>
                        {/*Trying to get the input here so that I can put it into my POST request*/}
                        <TextField inputRef={this.newActivity} type="activity" id="standard-basic" label="Standard" defaultValue={this.state.activity} />
                    </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button onClick={this.callAPI} variant="contained" startIcon={<UpdateIcon />} style={buttonStyle} >Uppdatera</Button>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <Button variant="contained" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} style={buttonStyle} >Ta Bort</Button>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` is a wrapper component.

You can pass the `ref` to the native `input` like this:

```js
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';

import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class App extends Component {
  ref = createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TextField inputProps={{ ref: this.ref }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```